# TileControl Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro, devexpress

I have developed an application using TileControl 
and on Clicking the Tiles, it is navigating to forms.
The forms contains GridControl and when I am performing double click event on gridview,it is navigating to another form and displaying a result.
Now the Problem is, when i am clicking the back button of Tile Menu,it is directly showing the main menu,instead of form having GridControl.
I want to show the GridControl first and then the Main Menu.
Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I far as I can see you are using the [DocumentManager](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11359) and it's [WindowsUIView](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11358).

To make it possible to navigate back from the current screen(with item detail) to upper level(with grid) you should make the current content container aware to it's parent container via [ContentConteiner.Parent](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsWindowsUIBaseContentContainer_Parenttopic) property.
Thus your containers hierarchy should looks like this:

```
// mainTileContainer(MainMenu) 
//  -> gridItemsPage(GridControl)
//    -> itemDetailPage(DetailForm)
//...
mainTileContainer.ActivationTarget = gridItemsPage;
gridItemsPage.Parent = mainTileContainer;
itemDetailPage.Parent = gridItemsPage;
```

Related links:

1. [Content Containers](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11771)
2. [Hierarchy and Screens](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11770)
3. [How To: Create Content Containers Hierarchy](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11812)