# DevExpress MetroUI Problems

Tags: winforms, microsoft-metro, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Actually,I have done my application using DevExpress MetroUIView.
I have a TileContainer and on clicking tile, it is showing GridView page and on doubleclick on GridView, it is navigating to Details page.
Up to now, everything works fine.
My problem is: when I click back button at the details page, it is directly navigating to TileContainer page instead of GridView page.
I want in a way like, when I click back button from Details page, it should redirect to GridView page and if I click back button on Gridview page, it should redirect to TileContainer screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TileControl Devexpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574381/tilecontrol-devexpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for the DevExpress [DocumentManager](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11359) version v12.2 and it's [WindowsUIView](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11358)(MetroUIView):

To make it possible to navigate back from the current screen(with item detail) to upper level(with grid) you should make the current content container aware to it's parent container via [ContentConteiner.Parent](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsWindowsUIBaseContentContainer_Parenttopic) property.
Thus your containers hierarchy should looks like this:

```
// mainTileContainer(MainMenu) 
//  -> gridItemsPage(GridControl)
//    -> itemDetailPage(DetailForm)
//...
mainTileContainer.ActivationTarget = gridItemsPage;
gridItemsPage.Parent = mainTileContainer;
itemDetailPage.Parent = gridItemsPage;
```

Related links:

1. [Content Containers](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11771)
2. [Hierarchy and Screens](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11770)
3. [How To: Create Content Containers Hierarchy](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11812)

Comment: Actually,I am having many Grid's, But the Details Page is only 1.
I cant just fix a parent statically to that Details Page.

Comment: You can set the `itemDetailPage.Parent` dynamically when navigating, using the WindowsUIView.ContentContainerActivated event

Comment: Also you can set the `itemDetailPage.Parent` before calling this page activation. Anyway the Back button aware only the proper navigation tree structure, thus you should only set the correct value for the `itemDetailPage.Parent` property...